# Correct no-SQL database strategy to query for aggregated graph data?

Tags: mongodb, highcharts, nosql

I'm helping a friend create an internal questionnaire that a company will use to test its own CSRs.

Secret testers will call or email a certain CSR and fill out a 40-question questionnaire.

The company has 5 regions worldwide and many CSRs.

In the end they want to see graph data that compares (at least) the total scores of all 5 regions over a year, divided by month.

So I'm thinking that over 5 years or so, there could be something like 500+ individual documents in the Tests collection.

Each document/test would have a:

```
totalScore
maxPossibleScore
regionId
dateCreated
csrId
```

What's the best practice to query for and aggregate all that data into an object so that it can be displayed on something like Highcharts?

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic

Say that I'm displaying a chart showing all scores for all regions in the year 2014.

On the page load, I can query for all tests that have a dateCreated of 2014 and return the `totalScore`, `maxPossibleScore`, `regionId`. That will give me back an array of objects and I can loop through that to get the info necessary to display the chart.

BUT would querying through 500+ individual documents and bringing back all this data be really time-consuming on each load of the graph?

EDIT:

I know this is kind of broad. What do you guys need to know to make the question more specific?

Comment: You are optimizing too early.  Code up a test, query your 500+ documents, did it take too long?  If so, optimize your query... Then rinse and repeat.  I don't know `mongodb` but I'd be really surprised if 500 documents took anytime at all.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks! I'm new to coding in general, so I currently don't have any bearing or gut feel on what amounts would take a "long" time, hence why I asked. All I know is that people say no-sql DBs are "slow", whatever that means. Would slowness start to develop only when I'm querying like 10 THOUSAND documents or something all at once?

Comment: 500 documents of the structure you've proposed is nothing. Even 10000 wouldn't be any problem to retrieve - the worse part would be piping that many over the network if that's what you had to do. Especially since you are new, start off by trying something and fix it once it's broken. And who told you no sql databases are slow?